# laravel-echo The POST method is not supported for this route

Tags: angular, laravel, socket.io, laravel-echo

so I'm trying to connect to a private channel using Laravel Echo. I am able to connect to a public channel but I'm getting issues authenticating a (logged in with correct Bearer token) private channel - getting the following error from `laravel-echo-server start`

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.6.2

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!

[10:58:39 PM] - Preparing authentication request to: https://example.co.uk
[10:58:39 PM] - Sending auth request to: https://example.co.uk/api/broadcasting/auth/

⚠ [10:58:39 PM] - K1cJaXs7jWMBNpF9AAAA could not be authenticated to private-sonect_database_user.2
{"errors":{"message":"The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."}}
Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 401
```

I'm confused by the error `POST method is not supported` because all POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE all work in my Laravel project. Furthermore, I am able to hit `https://example.co.uk/api/broadcasting/auth/` using Postman with a POST request.

Here's a sample of `php artisan route:list`

```
| Domain | Method        | URI                                           | Name                              | Action                                                                    | Middleware   |
|        | GET|POST|HEAD | api/broadcasting/auth                         |                                   | Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastController@authenticate                  | auth:api     |
```

PlayerEvent.php

```
namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class PlayerEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('user.' . $this->user->id);
    }

    /**
     * The event's broadcast name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'PlayerEvent';
    }

    /**
     * The event's broadcast name.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['message' => 'Hello world'];
    }

}
```

BroadcaseServiceProvider.php

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(["prefix" => "api", "middleware" => "auth:api"]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
```

config/app.php

```
        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
```

routes/channel.php

```
Broadcast::channel('user.{user}', function ($user) {
    return true;
});
```

laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
    "authHost": "https://example.co.uk",
    "authEndpoint": "/api/broadcasting/auth/",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "4cb2c72910d85007",
            "key": "d3af62258887434b9900b89a937cb7f7"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        },
        "publishPresence": true
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "https",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "/var/www/example.co.uk/letsencrypt/live/example.co.uk/fullchain.pem",
    "sslKeyPath": "/var/www/example.co.uk/letsencrypt/live/example.co.uk/privkey.pem",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": "http://localhost:4200/",
        "allowMethods": "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

I'm using angular on the front end

echo.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
import {UserModel} from "../models/user.model";
import * as io from "socket.io-client";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EchoService {

    public echo: Echo;

    constructor() {
        window['io'] = io;
        this.echo = window['Echo'] = new Echo({
            broadcaster: 'socket.io',
            host: environment.websocketUrl, // https://example.co.uk:6001
            auth: {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /** privateChannel('user', 'PlayerEvent', this.user); Called from elsewhere */
    privateChannel(channelName: string, eventName: string, user: UserModel) {
        console.log('privateChannel');
        this.echo.private( environment.broadcastChannelPrefix + channelName + '.' + user.id)
            .listen('.' + eventName, data => {
                console.log(data);
            });
    }
}
```

Laravel: 7.12.0
laravel-echo: ^1.8.0
socket.io-client: ^2.3.0
Angular: 9.1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it. Bit of an obvious one when I realised...
It's to do with my development environment - I have a virtual machine running where I've edited my `/etc/hosts/` file to point example.co.uk to. Since laravel-echo authenticates the user from the server, example.co.uk now points to my live server where that route isn't properly setup.

Changing my `/etc/hosts` file on the virtual machine to point to:

```
192.168.33.10     example.co.uk
```

Fixed the issue